# Python - Adjusting a function to accept an array instead of a single value

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, mask

EDIT:
I've made some progress on testing this out on a simple level, and now want to expand to a for loop. I've updated the question.

---

I have a function that take a three dimensional array and masks certain elements within the array based on specific conditions. See below:

```
#function for array masking
def masc(arr,z):
        return(np.ma.masked_where((arr[:,:,2] <= z+0.05)*(arr[:,:,2] >= z-0.05), arr[:,:,2]))
```

arr is a 3D array and z is a single value.

I now want to iterate this for multiple Z values. Here is an example with 2 z values:

```
masked_array1_1 = masc(xyz,z1)
masked_array1_2 = masc(xyz,z2)

masked_1 = masked_array1_1.mask + masked_array1_2.mask
masked_array1 = np.ma.array(xyz[:,:,2],mask=masked_1)
```

The masked_array1 gives me exactly what i'm looking for.

I've started to write a forloop to iterate this over a 1D array of Z values:

```
mask_1 = xyz[:,:,2]
for i in range(Z_all_dim):
    mask_1 += (masc(xyz,IWX_new[0],IWY_new[0],MWX[0],MWY[0],Z_all[i]).mask)

masked_array1 = np.ma.array(xyz[:,:,2], mask = mask_1)
```

Z_all is an array of 7 unique z values. This code does not work but i feel like i'm very close. Does anyone see if i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: try putting `@np.vectorize` before your function

Comment: @TomMcLean I tried created a new function vmask where it's np.vectorize(masc), but when i call it with an array for Z i get the error "invalid index to scalar variable"

Comment: @Tom, `np.vectorize` would be harder to use and slower than a simple loop on the elements of `z`.

Comment: @hpaulj can you show me how this would work with a loop? That's where i'm struggling.

Comment: Focus your code and question.  Looks like all those `ifs` on `XYxy` are unimportant.  `z` is used the same why in each. Calling the function many times for different `z` should be trivial.  But combining the masks may be more difficult.  Or creating a mask with with array.  Anyways, as written your question scares off all but the most determined helper.

Comment: @hpaulj I see what you're saying. I tried to cut all of the useless information from the question.

Comment: @hpaulj do the edits clarify the question?